# Matlab: if condition when diemnsion of two matrices are not equal

Tags: matlab, formula

I have two matrices that depends on the choice there would be some other computations. For example assume:

```
A =

 8     9     3
 9     6     5
 2     1     9
```

and

```
B =

 11     9    11     8     2
  2     2     8     9     8
 11     5     1     9     1
 11    11    10     5     4
  6     9    11     8     1
```

Now, I would choose one of them as new matirix

```
C = A;
C = B;
```

If I use the following `if` condition I would have an error.

```
if C==A
   %do some computation
else if C == B
   %do some other computation
else
   %print an error
```

Because The dimension of matrices are not equal then I have an error. Would you please let me know how I could formulate this in right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MATLAB provides a function to evaluate array equality: [`isequal`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html).

So try:

```
if isequal(C,A)
   %do some computation
else if isequal(C,B)
   %do some other computation
else
   %print an error
```

Comment: Note: `isequal` performs same checks as @ItamarKatz code; but it's a built-in function

Comment: @Saber It is good that you accepted an answer. However, many people do not look at questions with an accepted answer. I think it would be good to leave it open for, let's say a day, so that the answers can gain more votes and the posters get more value for their efforts.

Comment: @kkuilla I disagree. [`Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). I would rather you encouraged people to look at already answered questions in hopes of providing better answers. SO shouldn't be a popularity contest.

Comment: Well, you can word it however you want. Many do not look at questions with accepted answers. Leaving it open for a day will increase your chances of getting more answers. The folks who have read your (and my) comment probably read questions with accepted answers anyway and don't need encouragement.

Answer (score 3):

You can add another condition for the size, note that if the size condition does not hold, the 2nd condition is not checked, so you won't get an error:

```
if all(size(C)==size(A)) && all(C==A)
    %do some computation
elseif all(size(C)==size(B)) && all(C == B)
    %do some other computation
else
    %print an error
end
```

Note also that the condition should be `all(C==A)`.